# How/why is `date` detecting multiple timezone parts for input format `yyyymmddThhmmssZ`

Tags: bash, date, datetime, timezone

While attempting to parse AWS log filenames with embedded timestamps, I ran across the following

```
$ date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.30
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie

$ realpath /etc/localtime
/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York

$ echo $TZ


$ date --utc --date='20211114T0155Z' --debug
date: parsed number part: (Y-M-D) 2021-11-14
date: parsed zone part: UTC+07
date: parsed number part: 01:55:00
date: parsed zone part:
date: input timezone: parsed date/time string (+00)
date: error: seen multiple time-zone parts
date: invalid date ‘20211114T0155Z’
```

While talking with co-workers (in multiple timezones), it appears that some shells may find a timezone of `UTC-07` instead of my (WSL2 Ubuntu) `UTC+7` regardless of actual timezone. This may be either due to OSX specifically or do to a version difference (my OSX coworkers appear to have `date` version 9 while I'm running 8.3).

I've looked through `info date` and haven't found anything that looks like it explains this. On the contrary, Section 29.5 contains the following:

> The ISO 8601 date and time of day extended format consists of an ISO
> 8601 date, a ‘T’ character separator, and an ISO 8601 time of day.  This
> format is also recognized if the ‘T’ is replaced by a space

Despite this section saying a `T` is equivalent to a space, this does not appear to be true:

```
$ date --utc --date='20211114T0155Z'
date: invalid date ‘20211114T0155Z’

$ date --utc --date='20211114 0155Z'
Sun Nov 14 01:55:00 UTC 2021
```

Comment: `20211114` is not "an ISO 8601 date" (missing hyphens) and `0155` is not "an ISO 8601 time of day" (missing colon)

Comment: @glennjackman `20211114T0155Z` is ISO 8601 "basic format" compared to `2021-11-14T01:55Z` in "extended format"

Comment: @glennjackman Regardless of whether or not it's an ISO 8601 date or not, from the debug output it's clear that it's parsing the correct data. The problem is that it is also determining some phantom timezone before it attempts to parse the actual timezone specifier `Z`, and it's that phantom timezone that is the focus of this question since `date` fails due to seeing both the phantom and actual timezsone -- but only when using `T` as the date/time separator.

Comment: I suggest you spend some time carefully reading [Date input formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html) which documents how GNU date parses datetimes.

Comment: Also, I can confirm exactly what you're reporting on both MacOS with date from homebrew (v9.0) and WSL on Windows (v8.3). The solution is to add `-` as separators in the date part and `:` as separators in the time part.

Comment: @glennjackman I completely understand how to work around the issue I'm presenting here.  I'm attempting to _understand_ the inconsistencies in the behaviour of the `date` utility between my understanding _and_ it's own documentation. This isn't an issue with the format of the input data per-se since it works correctly using a space between the date and time and fails when using a `T`, despite the fact that the documents say those should behave identically.  There is some other logic kicking in here and so far I've yet to find it.

Comment: Note: you can also verify this isn't an input format issue by removing the final `Z` and observing the output of the `--debug` information. It's parsing the correct date/time data, just the wrong time zone: `date --utc --date='TZ="UTC" 20211114T0155' --debug` yields `date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2021-11-14 01:55:00 TZ=+07'` which is correct except for the timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this boils down to the heuristic being used in `parse-datetime` is determining that this is in military time instead of ISO 8601 basic format.

I haven't traced through all of `parse-datetime` yet, but I believe the difference in sign of the "phantom timezone" between `date` versions 8.3 and 9 is coming from [gnulib#5c438e8](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/commit/0673d8ab42c9bb0cf618a21b537cdd8fb976fb73) and that seems like fairly strong evidence that this is what is happening.  Additionally, without being familiar with this library at all, it seems reasonable that [this parser section](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/parse-datetime.y#L751-L775) may be generating this phantom timezone specifically.

This feels like a bug in the `parse-datetime` implementation, but for now I feel like my curiosity is appeased.

I'll leave this question open for a while longer in case someone with more experience has a better answer, which I'd accept over this at any point, now or in the future.